# Background color in label text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, background-color

Hi guys i need to do something like this in iOS. I've tried to highlight text in label but the result is not correct. Some idea in objective C ?[image]

I need do this in a uitableviewcell so i've to do this programmatically and not in storyboard. Text should change and be in 1 lines , 2 lines , 3 lines

Comment: What have you tried for till now?

Answer (score 2):

Set attributed string with background color of text.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
NSString * textStr = @"This is test label text with blue background color";

//Attributed text
NSMutableAttributedString *attrbStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: textStr];

//background color to attributed text
[attrbStr addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
          value:[UIColor blueColor]
          range:NSMakeRange(0, attrbStr.length)];

label.attributedText = attrbStr;
```

Comment: the problem is that this solution highlight " " character or "\n" character... i need only letters highlighted

Comment: Can you please share exact design/snapshot?

Comment: the exact design is the img i've already shared in this post, can you see it ?